# Sub using IF(INDEX()) gives #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I am tiring to do

If there is a cell in col C that matches a cell in col A then on that row the cell in col N =1 all other cells in col N =0

In my Sub I keep getting #N/A in all cells

Thanks

```
Sub Match()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Source")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("N2:N" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(INDEX('Source'!A:A,MATCH($A2,'Source'!$C:$C,0))<> "" "",1,0)"

Range("N2:N" & LastRow).Copy
Range("N2:N" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("N1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Grouping"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach. Looping through cells with VBA, in my experience, goes faster than trying to use the `MATCH` function. It doesn't have to calculate anything this way.

(I also like to name my ranges, since finding the last row via the VBA isn't always reliable. So I'd probably start by naming my A range and then referring to that range. Or I'd throw up an inputbox and let the user select the range dynamically. But I'll work with the model you have.)

```
Sub Match()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim matchRange As Range
    Dim testRange As Range
    Dim foundIt As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Source")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set matchRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    Set testRange = ws.Range("N2:N" & LastRow)

    For Each c In testRange.Cells
        Set foundIt = matchRange.Find(What:=c.Value, _
                                      LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                      SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                      MatchCase:=False)

        If Not foundIt Is Nothing Then
            c.Value2=1
        End If
    Next c

    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Grouping"

End Sub
```

Comment: tmoore82, thank you, `testRange = ws.Range("N2:N" & LastRow)` needs to be `testRange = ws.Range("E2:E" & LastRow)` and `outputRange = ws.Range("N2:N" & LastRow)` I need not to over wright the `testRange` is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your follow-up question. Are you asking to modify the above code so it references Column E instead of A, or is this an additional step? And can you elaborate on what you mean by not overwriting `testRange`? Do you mean the variable or the actual cell values?

Comment: tmoore82, I appreciate your replys, I was not clear.  ` I need to look at each cell in E2:E and compare it to the range of cells in B2:B. If there is a match, then "1" is entered in the corresponding cell in column L else "0" is entered:~

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Sub MyMatch()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Source")

    With ws
        LastRow = ws.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("N2:N" & LastRow)
            .Formula = "=1*ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2,'Source'!$C:$C,0))"
            .Value = .Value
        End With

        .Range("N1").FormulaR1C1 = "Grouping"
    End With
End Sub
```

**Notes:**

1. Your approach with formulas is *much faster* than loop+find.
2. `ISNUMBER(MATCH(..))` returns `False` if `Match` doesn't find anything (because it this case `Match` returns `#N/A` and it's not a number), and `True` otherwise. Part `=1*ISNUMBER(..)` converts `True`/`False` to `1`/`0`.
3. I changed `Copy/PasteSpecial` to `.Value = .Value` - it's faster
4. I've changed name of your sub to avoid confusing situations (since there is built-in function `Application.Match`)

Comment: simoco, thanks for the code, it is much faster but it is not finding the matches, or every thing is a match as it returns `1` for every cell thank you.

Comment: Tim, it returns 1 in column N if corresponding value in column A is found in column C, and 0 otherwise (this requirements is from your question)

Comment: @simoco, is it always faster to use a matching formula? Is that scalable? I was recently working with two lists, one 40k and one 60k, and I had better luck with loop+find than with matching in terms of workability. It took a while for the macro to run, but when I was using Match (no macro, just filling a series of cells), I kept running into processing issues in the workbook.

Comment: in general built-in functions _much faster_ than VBA (because they was written in C). For sheet with many formulas I would add `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual` in the beggining of macro and `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic` in the end to prevent sheet recalculation during execution.

Comment: I wondered about that as well, thanks for the question and the answer.